# Installing ubuntu on windows 7 machine

Tags: ubuntu, installation

When trying to install ubuntu using usb on windows 7 machine. I am getting this kernel panic unknown-block(2 0)

Attaching the screen capture for details[image]. Kindly have a look.

Can someone please suggest what can be the reason. I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: Your screenshot is clipped and it is not clear at which stage it panics: during installation or after. Describe your platform (hardware, disk partitioning, intention), what steps you have performed, at which point the failure occurred, what you have done trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a problem with your file system. Could be plenty of things, bad installation, a partition problem or maybe your hard drive is failing. If it's a partition problem you should run fsck from a live distro.